# Image/Picture on a messagebox C#

Tags: image, messagebox

Is it possible to add a picture to a messagebox in C# besides the customized buttons?

or

How do I put the picture I want as a custom Icon?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible.

Instead you can use a `Form` to show the image. You message box will be just like any other form in your application.

Comment: Can I put a custom icon as a picture?

Answer (score 0):

It is useful to have such type of facility while coding with C#, but reality is it is not as relevant as we think.

a good practice is to use Forms instead of putting things in MessageBox.

Try it I hope it helps !!